# PeerJS: iceConnectionState is disconnected, closing connections to [userid]

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

I used [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/docs/) for my application [a voice and video chat application] and everything works great, connection to peer, video and voice call where working fine while development and testing was done on the same network until i hosted the application online. It stopped connecting to peers and keep reporting

PeerJS:  iceConnectionState is disconnected, closing connections to [userid]

and

Error: Negotiation of connection to [userid] failed.
    at RTCPeerConnection.pc.oniceconnectionstatechange [as onicechange].

Any ideas on solving this issue?

Comment: Got the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem.

I had to buy ICE and TURN servers from Twilio to fix it. This gives me reliable connection and faster messaging.

You can try that.

Comment: Same situation, it's works fine the local development environment, on that time it's not needed the ICE and TURN settings.

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer and agree with Aminu.  I found Twilio's TURN servers to be a good solution.  I thought I'd give more detail in case it helped anyone.

I already have a Twilio account so that made it extra easy.

I made a PHP function to get me some Ice Servers. Like this...

```
define("TWILIO_ACC_ID","AC12345etc...");
define("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN","8675309");

require_once '/path/to/my/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

function twilio_iceServers() {
    $twilio=new Client(TWILIO_ACC_ID,TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
    
    $token = $twilio->tokens->create();
    
    return json_encode($token->iceServers);

}
```

Then for my javascript I load in my ice servers like this:

```
var twilio_iceServers=<?php print(twilio_iceServers()); ?>;
```

Then include those ice servers in my peerJS configs like this:

```
var peer_options={
    key:'myKey',
    host:'my.host.com',
    port: 443,
    secure: true,
    config: {iceServers:twilio_iceServers}
};
```

Seems like these Ice Servers expire in about a day.  Since with my app people could be leaving the window open for days at a time, I had to build a way to have those servers renewed.

```
//returns current time stamp in seconds
function now() {
    return Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
}

//some variable that keeps track of whether I'm on a call or not
var call_status=null;

//save the current time stamp into the ice servers object on page load
twilio_iceServers.date=now();

//do a check every 60 seconds to see if the ice servers have expired.  yes... not 12 hours
setInterval(function(){

    //if ice server issued date is more than 12 hours ago AND we're not on a call.  we renew the ice servers.  If we are on a call, this will run about a minute after we get off the call.  This is why the setInterval is set to be 1 minute instead of 12 hours.
    if (twilio_iceServers.date<(now()-43200) && !call_status) {
        
        $.post("/page/on/my/server/that/just/sends/back/twilio_iceServers",{},function(data) {
            if (data) {
                //save the new ice servers
                twilio_iceServers=JSON.parse(data);
                //save the new date of the server
                twilio_iceServers.date=now();
                
            }
        });
        
    }

},60000);
```

Is this all the REAL way to do all this?  I DON'T KNOW!  But it works for me.  So there.

Comment: I am trying to use the twilio ice servers as you have done. I have the relevent ice server and call new Peer(myId,options) where options is as below, and iceServers is as returned from twilio:-

var peerOptions = { options: { secure: true, config: { iceServers:  } } };

Connection seem sucessful, but chrome://webrtc-internals/ shows the following:-

 { iceServers: [stun:stun.l.google.com:19302, turn:0.peerjs.com:3478], etc ....}

Making me believe I am using the google servers. How can I verify I am using twilio?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with the goings-on of Ice Servers to answer this.  Good luck!